# Tensorflow how to generate unbalanced combined data sets

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a question about the new dataset API (tensorflow 1.4). I have two data sets and I need to create a combined unbalanced data set, i.e.
each batch should contain a certain number of elements from the first and a certain number of elements from the second data set. For example,

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant([1,1,1,1,1,1]
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant([2,2,2,2,2,2]))
```

assuming a batch size of 4 I want a batch in the combined data set to look like [1,1,1,2]. I know how to generate a balanced data set using zip and flat_map
but I'm at a loss with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this problem, my solution is to batch the datasets individually, zipping them and then mapping a `tf.concat` operator on the generated dataset.

In your example it would give something like (I renamed the second dataset `dataset2`) :

```
def concat(*tensor_list):
    return tf.concat(tensor_list, axis=0)

zipped_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset1.batch(3), dataset2))
unbalanced_ds = zipped_ds.map(concat)
```

If the dataset is a nested structure of tensors, you can use the following version of concat :

```
def concat(*ds_elements):
    #Create one empty list for each component of the dataset
    lists = [[] for _ in ds_elements[0]]
    for element in ds_elements:
        for i, tensor in enumerate(element):
            #For each element, add all its component to the associated list
            lists[i].append(tensor)

    #Concatenate each component list
    return tuple(tf.concat(l, axis=0) for l in lists)
```

Works if all datasets elements (part of the dataset you want to combine) are tensors for which only outermost dimension (the relative batch size) differs. It builds one list for each component of a dataset element, and concatenate these components indepedantly from each other.

Which handle one level of nesting. If you need more, you can use recurrence to go and unpack nested nest, but it will probably give a not so clean computation graph...